# How to gracefully handle the SIGKILL signal in Java

Tags: java, sigkill

How do you handle clean up when the program receives a kill signal?

For instance, there is an application I connect to that wants any third party app (my app) to send a `finish` command when logging out. What is the best say to send that `finish` command when my app has been destroyed with a `kill -9`?

edit 1: kill -9 cannot be captured. Thank you guys for correcting me.

edit 2: I guess this case would be when the one calls just kill which is the same as ctrl-c

Comment: `kill -9` means to me: "Begone, foul process, away with thee!", upon which the process will cease to be.  Immediately.

Comment: On most *nixes that I'm aware of, kill -9 cannot be intercepted and gracefully handled by any program no matter what language it was written in.

Comment: @Begui: in addition to what the others have commented and answered, *IF* your Un*x OS doesn't instantly kill *AND REGAIN ALL RESOURCES* used by the program being *kill -9'ed*, well... The OS is broken.

Comment: About the kill -9 command, the manpage says more precisely: "9       KILL (non-catchable, non-ignorable kill)". SIGKILL a signal that is handled by the OS, not the application.

Comment: Amazing how SO is such a complete source for knowledge AND fun! @ZoogieZork had me laughing for minutes, alone at the couch, with his (I'm assuming he is a guy) very peculiar explanation of the -9 switch hahaha. Made my day, indeed!

Comment: Just `kill` is not the same as Ctrl-C, as `kill` without specifying which signal to send will send SIGTERM, whereas Ctrl-C sends SIGINT.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

It is **impossible** for any program, in any language, to handle a SIGKILL. This is so it is always possible to terminate a program, even if the program is buggy or malicious.  But SIGKILL is not the only means for terminating a program. The other is to use a SIGTERM. Programs *can* handle that signal. The program *should* handle the signal by doing a controlled,  but rapid, shutdown. When a computer shuts down, the final stage of the shutdown process sends every remaining process a SIGTERM, gives those processes a few seconds grace, then sends them a SIGKILL.

The way to handle this for anything **other** than `kill -9` would be to register a [shutdown](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) hook. If you can use (**SIGTERM**) `kill -15` the shutdown hook will work. (**SIGINT**) `kill -2` **DOES** cause the program to gracefully exit and run the shutdown hooks.

> Registers a new virtual-machine shutdown hook.
>
> The Java virtual machine shuts down in response to two kinds of events:
>
> - The program exits normally, when the last non-daemon thread exits or when the exit (equivalently, System.exit) method is invoked, or
> - The virtual machine is terminated in response to a user interrupt, such as typing ^C, or a system-wide event, such as user logoff or system shutdown.

I tried the following test program on OSX 10.6.3 and on `kill -9` it did **NOT** run the shutdown hook, as expected. On a `kill -15` it **DOES** run the shutdown hook every time.

```
public class TestShutdownHook
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                System.out.println("Shutdown hook ran!");
            }
        });

        while (true)
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

There isn't any way to really gracefully handle a `kill -9` in any program.

> In rare circumstances the virtual
>   machine may abort, that is, stop
>   running without shutting down cleanly.
>   This occurs when the virtual machine
>   is terminated externally, for example
>   with the SIGKILL signal on Unix or the
>   TerminateProcess call on Microsoft
>   Windows.

The only real option to handle a `kill -9` is to have another watcher program watch for your main program to go away or use a wrapper script. You could do with this with a shell script that polled the `ps` command looking for your program in the list and act accordingly when it disappeared.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

java TestShutdownHook
wait
# notify your other app that you quit
echo "TestShutdownHook quit"
```

Answer (score 18):

I would expect that the JVM gracefully **interrupts** ([`thread.interrupt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt())) all the running threads created by the application, at least for signals [`SIGINT (kill -2)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGINT) and [`SIGTERM (kill -15)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGTERM).

This way, the signal will be forwarded to them, allowing a gracefully thread cancellation and resource finalization in the [standard ways](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html).

**But this is not the case** (at least in my JVM implementation: `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17), Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)`.

As other users commented, the usage of **shutdown hooks** seems mandatory.

So, how do I would handle it?

Well first, I do not care about it in all programs, only in those where I want to keep track of user cancellations and unexpected ends. For example, imagine that your java program is a process managed by other. You may want to differentiate whether it has been terminated gracefully (`SIGTERM` from the manager process) or a shutdown has occurred (in order to relaunch automatically the job on startup).

As a basis, I always make my long-running threads periodically aware of interrupted status and throw an `InterruptedException` if they interrupted. This enables execution finalization in way controlled by the developer (also producing the same outcome as standard blocking operations). Then, at the top level of the thread stack, `InterruptedException` is captured and appropriate clean-up performed. These threads are coded to known how to respond to an interruption request. High [cohesion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)) design.

So, in these cases, I add a shutdown hook, that does what I think the JVM should do by default: interrupt all the non-daemon threads created by my application that are still running:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Interrupting threads");
        Set<Thread> runningThreads = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
        for (Thread th : runningThreads) {
            if (th != Thread.currentThread() 
                && !th.isDaemon() 
                && th.getClass().getName().startsWith("org.brutusin")) {
                System.out.println("Interrupting '" + th.getClass() + "' termination");
                th.interrupt();
            }
        }
        for (Thread th : runningThreads) {
            try {
                if (th != Thread.currentThread() 
                && !th.isDaemon() 
                && th.isInterrupted()) {
                    System.out.println("Waiting '" + th.getName() + "' termination");
                    th.join();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("Shutdown interrupted");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Shutdown finished");
    }
});
```

Complete test application at github: https://github.com/idelvall/kill-test

Answer (score 12):

There *are* ways to handle your own signals in certain JVMs -- see [this article about the HotSpot JVM](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/trouble/TSG-VM/html/signals.html) for example.

By using the Sun internal `sun.misc.Signal.handle(Signal, SignalHandler)` method call you are also able to register a signal handler, but probably not for signals like `INT` or `TERM` as they are used by the JVM.

To be able to handle *any* signal you would have to jump out of the JVM and into Operating System territory.

What I generally do to (for instance) detect abnormal termination is to launch my JVM inside a Perl script, but have the script wait for the JVM using the `waitpid` system call.

I am then informed whenever the JVM exits, and why it exited, and can take the necessary action.

Comment: Note you *can* capture `INT` and `TERM` with `sun.misc.Signal`, but you can't handle `QUIT` because the JVM reserves it for debugging, nor `KILL` because the OS will terminate the JVM immediately.  Attempting to handle either will raise an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Answer (score 8):

Reference https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/graceful-shutdowns-with-ecs/

```
import sun.misc.Signal;
import sun.misc.SignalHandler;
 
public class ExampleSignalHandler {
    public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
        final long start = System.nanoTime();
        Signal.handle(new Signal("TERM"), new SignalHandler() {
            public void handle(Signal sig) {
                System.out.format("\nProgram execution took %f seconds\n", (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1e9f);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        int counter = 0;
        while(true) {
            System.out.println(counter++);
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(...)`, but you cannot be guaranteed that it will be called *in any case*.

Comment: But in the case of kill -9 it almost certainly won't run.

Answer (score 3):

There is one way to react to a kill -9: that is to have a separate process that monitors the process being killed and cleans up after it if necessary. This would probably involve IPC and would be quite a bit of work, and you can still override it by killing both processes at the same time. I assume it will not be worth the trouble in most cases.

Whoever kills a process with -9 should theoretically know what he/she is doing and that it may leave things in an inconsistent state.