# how to make sure something happen once the tomcat stop or restart

Tags: tomcat, jvm

Sometimes, tomcat restart will cause my application stop immediately so that my consuming data in oracle db keep one error state. So I want know if has any methods to help handling the state once the tomcat stop. Due to unknown the actual events happen on the stop procedure of tomcat. I can't know how to make sure something happen when tomcat stopped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing a normal restart you should be able to register a shutdownhook and have it run before the server kills the app.

Check out the javadocs for more detailed info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread).

You can add a shutdown hook like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
         // clean-up logic
    }
}));
```

Comment: Thanks. I have another issue: when tomcat stop. if the shutdown of all thread is through thread.interrupt. If so. I can judge interrupted state to make sure something done?

Comment: I'm not sure that I fully understand your question. There are a few different ways that the thread can be stopped. A Kill -9 is very different than a graceful shutdown of the server. This answer provides a ton of details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2541618/1442761.

Comment: maybe I hadn't explain it clearly. My mean is what influences on existed running thread when stop jvm. Many thanks to you!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can register a `LifecycleListener` for your tomcat application ([link](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html#Lifecycle_Listeners)).  A lifecycle listener will be called when your context is loaded and right after it is being closed.

Here is a more involved explanation [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14017/filters.htm#i1000654).  You might want to look at the `contextInitialized` and `contextDestroyed` methods of the `ServletContextListener` interface.

Comment: Thanks. I have another issue: when tomcat stop. if the shutdown of all thread is through thread.interrupt. If so. I can judge interrupted state to make sure something done?

Comment: On the `contextDestroyed` method you can actually stop the threads.  You just have to keep track of the threads you start in `contextInitialized`.