# Python: call function on any kind of termination

Tags: python

From reading documentation and other questions here, I see different examples for how to execute functions on `SIGINT`, `SIGTERM`, on calls to `sys.exit()`, etc.

Is there any way to register a function to run on **any kind** of termination? **"any kind"** means:

1. Regular exit using sys.exit() or when the flow ends
2. An uncaught error that crashes the application
3. External various killing signals

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html?

Comment: Note: The functions registered via this module are **not** called when the program is killed by a signal not handled by Python, when a Python fatal internal error is detected, or when os._exit() is called.

Comment: Yes, there probably is no single answer to this question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31060517/how-to-use-atexit-when-exception-is-raised

Answer (score 0):

This is not generically possible. E.g. for SIGKILL, you user program has no control. The operating system will simply terminate it. Cf. [SIGKILL signal handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15766036/sigkill-signal-handling) or [SIGKILL signal Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908694/sigkill-signal-handler)

Comment: Let's currently ignore the `kill -9` kind of kill, that can't anyway be handled. I mean to all other termination types

Comment: Please update the question accordingly. SIGKILL is explicitly stated there.