# Java on kill method

Tags: java, kill

I have a java program which writes 1 file into multiple files, not all connections are open at the same time.

I want to add an method to remove all of these created files when the program is killed (by using ctrl-c in the command line).

Adding a shutdown hook is always executed when the object is shut down, I only want to remove them if the program is killed.
Is there an RuntimeException I can catch?

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: If you want to catch kill signal and do some stuff, here is your [answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2541618/354831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook()`. [Here's an example.](http://hellotojavaworld.blogspot.cz/2010/11/runtimeaddshutdownhook.html)

Comment: Does it recover the file to earlier state. I think the question is to roll back the operations performed in the files.

Comment: I think I found it because that site! First I will add a shutdownhook, and after all files are closed, I can remove this shutdownhook.

Comment: @SenthilPrabhu the question says "remove all of these created files" - nothing about rolling back the contents. The new files can be easily removed from the shutdown hook.

Comment: @TomA: Ok Tom..! I am sorry if it is the answer. The program writes one file content to multiple. So I just had a curiosity whether it can be rolled back to previous state.

Comment: Easiest way to enable a rollback-like functionality would be to first write the files into /tmp and then move them into place.

Comment: @TomA: I had the Same Idea of using temp files then change the files. There is no guarantee that the application may terminate at replacing with old files. I think i ve to move to database only.. :)