# Stop java file running in ssh

Tags: java, shell, ssh

Im running a jar file as part of a large web app. The majority of the app is written in php, but there is one large .jar file that it interacts with. To start this jar file I use ssh to connect to the server, navigate to the directory and run it by calling:

```
java -jar file_name.jar
```

If I want to turn off this file, what's the ssh command for that ?

Comment: Basically `kill -9 PID` (and milder variants) Where PID is the process id of the java process... ([relevant post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541597/how-to-gracefully-handle-the-sigkill-signal-in-java)) Or you could probably do some JMX based graceful shutdown too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While agreeing with other comments and answers, I'd like to point out the oft forgotten `jps` tool packaged with JDK's

```
anders@localhost:~$ jps -v
15688 Jps -Dapplication.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle -Xms8m
```

which lists all running Java processes on the host (might want to `sudo` if the process wasn't started by your login user).

So, with some command line magic such as

```
kill -9 `jps -v | grep file_name.jar | awk {'print $1'}`
```

you would achieve your stated purpose.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

If you do:

```
ps aux
```

or something similar (see `man ps` for the many different possible commands) you should be able to find the PID of the java process (might be difficult if there are many java processes running*).
Then do:

```
kill PID
```

If that doesn't work, try:

```
kill -9 PID
```

But this will not give the process a chance to shut down cleanly.

*) The reason this might be difficult with many java processes running, is that on some OS's, Java versions, etc, the process name *might* simply be "java", which makes it hard to distinguish them.

**Update:** Or you can use `pgrep -lf file_name.jar` to get the PID easier.
See https://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep

Comment: With `pgrep -lf file_name.jar` you'll find the PID faster.

Comment: I wasn't aware of `pgrep`. Sounds like a useful command. I used to do `ps aux | grep [KEY]` when I needed, but this would again be a problem if the java processes haven't got helpful names, but I'm not sure if that's a problem much (I just encountered it once or twice in the past) :)