# How do I cleanly shut down an embedded JRuby in response to a SIGTERM to the JVM process?

Tags: java, jvm, jruby, webrick

I am running a Middleman (which uses Webrick) server on JRuby inside a JVM process using the `org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer` API.

If I shutdown cleanly and stop the server from inside the JVM, everything works as expected.

But if I send a SIGTERM to the JVM process (for example, by hitting ctrl+C at the command line), the console returns but the JVM process does not terminate - it hangs around indefinitely until I send it a SIGKILL.

I tried registering a JVM shutdown hook to terminate the `ScriptingContainer` instance, but the hook never fires. I'm not sure why... perhaps JRuby is swallowing the SIGTERM somehow?

How can I get the JVM to shut all the way down, cleanly, even if it contains a running Webrick server?

Comment: Have you verified that the problem is JRuby, perhaps by swapping `ScriptingContainer` for a does-nothing implementation of [`org.jruby.embed.EmbedRubyInstanceConfigAdapter`](http://javadox.com/org.jruby/jruby-complete/1.7.13/org/jruby/embed/EmbedRubyInstanceConfigAdapter.html) and seeing if the problem persists?

Comment: Control-C doesn't send SIGTERM, it sends SIGINT

Comment: What OS are you on? Could you provide a thread dump of the JVM after you've hit ctrl+c? (run `jstack <pid>`) How do you check if your shutdown hook fires?

Comment: Following [WEBrick documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/WEBrick.html) I read it as WEBrick is able to install a SIGINT handler. So Middleman would do this part. Maybe the source of your problem is at a different place. Have you tried to connect to the session for example with `jconsole` to check which thread is still alive.

Comment: Are you creating any threads, or does the ScriptingContainer create any?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `kill -9` does not trigger the shutdownHook, but `kill -15` does.

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541597/how-to-gracefully-handle-the-sigkill-signal-in-java) has a detailed answer to the same problem.

Bottom line is, you're screwed, as there doesn't seem to exist any way to intercept a `kill -9` signal and perform some maintenance tasks before the JVM halts.

Comment: signal man page ""The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored.""", you can't really handle sigkill even in C program. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html

Comment: I don't need to handle SIGKILL... That is fine as it still results in a complete process shutdown. My problem is detecting and terminating on a SIGTERM or SIGINT.

Comment: SIGINT and SIGTERM signals were observed on Linux but in Windows it never sent these signals to the application.

Answer (score 0):

First, a debugging trick: you can send a `SIGQUIT` to a Java process to get it to print the current stack traces of all running threads. This can help you diagnose which threads are causing the JVM to not exit.

Sending a `SIGINT`, `SIGHUP`, or `SIGTERM` causes Java to run its shutdown hooks, then exit.  You can see this in [`java.lang.Terminator`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/solaris/classes/java/lang/Terminator.java).  Once the signal is received, [`java.lang.Shutdown`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/Shutdown.java) handles running all the shutdown hooks before terminating the process.  `Shutdown.halt()` is not called until after the shutdown hooks have all finished, which suggests you have a shutdown hook that is hanging.

Without actual code or stack traces it's difficult to provide a more precise answer than that, but a JVM that stays alive after you send a `SIGINT` is usually doing something strange in its shutdown hooks.  If this isn't enough to go on try sending a `SIGINT`, waiting a few seconds, then sending a `SIGQUIT`, and adding the resulting stack traces to the question.