# JVM hangs on exit

Tags: java, windows-8, jvm, java-8, pkcs#11

I am working on a small app that should sign documents using digital signature and quit.
The signature can be in a PKCS#12 archive (.pfx file) or on a smartcard device.

Working with the pfx file is easy and working fine.

However, sometimes using the smartcard device, the process hangs on Windows 8 PCs.

The document is signed correctly, but the process doesn't terminate. It just hangs.

I'm using the Sun's PKCS#11 provider - `sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11`

Basically I'm doing this:

```
SunPKCS11 provider = new SunPKCS11(configuration);
Security.addProvider(provider);

..... some work .....

provider.logout()
Security.removeProvider(provider);
```

Now... even if I call `System.exit(0)` or throw an exception at the end of the `main` method, I can see the stacktrace in the output but the process doesn't terminate.

I've added a shutdown hook to see if it is executed and it is, i.e. the JVM is trying to stop.

The hang occures rarely, only on Windows 8 PCs. Tried with different smartcards and it happens only with cards that use `cmp11.dll` (dlls are provided from the vendors of the smartcards).

Using the same dll for communication with the smartcard, however, works fine on Windows 7, XP or some Windows 8 PCs

Running it with Java 8, Update 45, on either x86 or x64 Windows 8

Tried to get a thread dump to see what is hanging:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // do my job, register provider, sign documents, remove provider ...

  for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
    System.err.println("Sleep... " + i);
    Thread.sleep(2 * 1000);
  }
  System.err.println("Exiting...");
}
```

If I execute `jstack -l 3232 > dump.log 2>&1` when `Sleep... x` is printing, everything looks OK.

However, if I execute `jstack -F -l 3232 > dump2.log 2>&1` when `Exiting...` is printed and the app hangs (using `-F` because the process hangs), i got the following:

```
Attaching to process ID 3232, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 25.45-b02
Deadlock Detection:

No deadlocks found.

Thread Exception in thread "main"         
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
      at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.runJStackTool(JStack.java:140)
      at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.main(JStack.java:106)
Caused by: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Windbg Error: GetThreadIdBySystemId failed!
      at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.windbg.WindbgDebuggerLocal.getThreadIdFromSysId0(Native Method)
      at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.windbg.WindbgDebuggerLocal.getThreadIdFromSysId(WindbgDebuggerLocal.java:284)
      at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.windbg.amd64.WindbgAMD64Thread.getThreadID(WindbgAMD64Thread.java:88)
      at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.windbg.amd64.WindbgAMD64Thread.toString(WindbgAMD64Thread.java:81)
      at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2982)
      at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:683)
      at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.win32_amd64.Win32AMD64JavaThreadPDAccess.printThreadIDOn(Win32AMD64JavaThreadPDAccess.java:114)
      at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.JavaThread.printThreadIDOn(JavaThread.java:265)
      at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.StackTrace.run(StackTrace.java:79)
      at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.StackTrace.run(StackTrace.java:45)
      at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.run(JStack.java:66)
      at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.startInternal(Tool.java:260)
      at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:223)
      at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.execute(Tool.java:118)
      at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.main(JStack.java:92)
      ... 6 more
```

I can see the process with PID 3232 in the task manager!

Any idea why it is not terminating or why `jstack` fails?

**EDIT**

---

Ok, tried to extract the signing in a separate process, execute it with `Runtime.exec` and then kill it with `Process.destroy` but... doesn't seem to help. The child process still stays in the task manager.

Aaaaand... now I have no other choice but to make it kill itself ;(

```
try {
  String name = java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill.exe /F /PID " + name.split("@")[0]);
}
catch(Throwable t) {
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill.exe /F /IM java.exe"); 
}
```

**EDIT 2**

---

Tried with `Runtime.halt` as well. Still doesn't terminate the process...

I would appreciate any ideas!

Comment: Have you tried examining the native threads using [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/cs-cz/sysinternals/processexplorer)? Or you can generate a dump and try to analyse it...Good luck!

Comment: Came across [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34012012/5128464)....

Comment: I had a similar problem with the same jstack error message. If I create a Windows Dump and run jhsdb jstack on it it does not help. When I inspect it with WinDBG there is only one thread left (sarted by the signal handler and hanging(!) in `ntdll!NtTerminateProcess+0xa`, Only taskkill /f helps in that case (and even though the process is gone then there is still a blocked TCP port which does not show up in netstat.

Answer (score 1):

This won't address your root cause, but this method can be used to force the JVM to terminate:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#halt(int)

As the Javadoc says, use with extreme caution ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I have some problem with sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 on Windows 8 PCs.This is working for me:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill.exe /F /PID " + name.split("@")[0]);
Thread.sleep(500);
```