# How To Identify JFrame is closed or exit

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am working with **Swing Application**. Can I identify that my JFrame window is **closed by abnormal condition of OS** like closed by **unavailability of power supply of my computer** or laptop **shutdown when my laptop battery discharge**.

Comment: I don't think you can.

Comment: Does your UPS have a Java API?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541597/how-to-gracefully-handle-the-sigkill-signal-in-java