# why process cannot be killed by signal 15 but 9 in linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, process

Recently, an exception has occurred on the project, which is the following scenario:

When the process runs for a long time, one of the threads is stuck, and the reason is not clear yet.

But one discovery is: when I use `kill 15` + `pid`, the process cannot be killed, but using `kill 9` can kill the process.

I've never encountered this before, so wondering if anyone knows?

I tried to find information from internet, but there is no relevant information that can solve this problem.
the process is in SL state.

Comment: A process can handle SIGTERM(15) and do anything (including ignoring it completely). SIGKILL(9) is handled by the kernel directly and a process cannot choose to ignore it. Closest existing answer I could find: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2541618/21105992

Comment: i did a singal handler with SIGTEAM(15),when receive the singal,will safety exit;but the process not running into it,there's no print.

Comment: Run the program under `strace`.

Comment: embedded system just only have gdb

Comment: Then run it under `gdb`, and monitor the threads.

Answer (score 2):

Because they both send different signals to the process.

From the Linux man page:

> The command kill sends the specified signal to the specified
> processes or process groups.
>
> If no signal is specified, the TERM signal is sent. The default
> action for this signal is to terminate the process. This signal
> should be used in preference to the KILL signal (number 9), since
> a process may install a handler for the TERM signal in order to
> perform clean-up steps before terminating in an orderly fashion.
> **If a process does not terminate after a TERM signal has been
> sent, then the KILL signal may be used; be aware that the latter
> signal cannot be caught, and so does not give the target process
> the opportunity to perform any clean-up before terminating.**

`kill -9` generates
`SIGKILL(9)` which, unlike `SIGTERM(15)`, can not be blocked, caught, or ignored by a process.

Why? Because it is designed to be so. It is equivalent to saying:

***“Away, you starvelling, you elf-skin, you dried neat’s-tongue,
bull’s-pizzle, you stock-fish!”***

to a process.